# An example of a nonlinear monotone operator $\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: calculus, monotone-operator-theory

I am preparing a note, and I am looking for a nice example of a monotone nonlinear operator $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, i.e., for all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^2$ $$(f(a)-f(b))^\top (a-b) \ge 0.$$
However, I failed to find any simple illustrative example; all textbook examples are either linear or rather weird and not really pedagogical. Could you please help with that?

**UPD:** To make the example more pedagogical, I am looking for
$$f(x) = \begin{bmatrix}f_1(x_1,x_2)\\f_2(x_1,x_2)\end{bmatrix}$$
rather than
$$f(x) = \begin{bmatrix}f_1(x_1)\\f_2(x_2)\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Why not $f(a_1, a_2) = (g(a_1), g(a_2))$ with $g$ any nonlinear monotone increasing function from reals to reals? Exponential for example

Comment: Because it is trivial and not really pedagogical. Saying $f(x_1,x_2) = [x_1, x_2]^\top$ is not illustrative.

Comment: $(e^{a_1}, e^{a_2})$ doesn't seem that trivial to me, but in any case you should probably add that restriction to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

$$f(x,y) = \big(1+\ln(x/y), -x/y \big)$$
for $x>0$ and $y>0$.

*Note:* This is the gradient of the Kullback-Leibler divergence
$x\ln(x/y)$ which is convex in $(x,y)$ so its gradient is monotone.

If you really need full domain, you can use
$$f(x,y) = (x^3-y,y^3+x)$$
which was obtained by adding the rotator by $\pi/2$ to the gradient of the convex function $\frac{1}{4}(x^4+y^4)$.